# Provided that I want to keep the HTML in a separate file, how can I pass PHP variables to the HTML before sending it out?

Tags: php, html

How do I pass a PHP variable to an HTML file (to be used as an email template) included with `file_get_contents`?

1. First I set some variables:

   ```
   $variable = 'Hello or else!';
   ```
2. I get the HTML/PHP email template like this:

   ```
   $html_email_body = file_get_contents('/var/www/folder/email.php');
   ```
3. In that PHP/HTML email file, I am using the pre-defined variables like this:

   ```
   <p><?php echo $variable; ?></p>
   ```
4. Then finally sending it out with PHPMailer.

   ```
   $mail->Body    = $email_body;
   PHPMailerFunc( $html_email_body );
   ```

The mailing works perfectly, but the HTML email content is blank where the `$variable` string should be.

**Provided that I want to keep the HTML in a separate file**, how can I pass PHP variables to the HTML before sending it out?

PS:  I know `file_get_contents` retrieves content and parses it into a string, so what I am doing can't really work.   Is there maybe some way to `include` the HTML?

**My code in the HTML template**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Email Title</title>
<style>
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
...
  </tr>
</table>
<p face="arial, sans, sans-serif"><?php echo $variable['key']; ?></p>
<p face="arial, sans, sans-serif"><?php echo $variable['key2']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

*I have tried doing `var_dump($variable)` and it contains the right stuff.

Comment: Have you tried appending the variable declaration as string?

Comment: The question in your title is completely different from the question in your text.

Comment: Long shot but try: You could replace the string <?php echo $var; ?> with %s, and use printf to substitute the value.

Comment: Show us the code in `/var/www/folder/email.php` it makes a big difference to the answer

Comment: Apologies for wrong title - I'm really confused about a lot of things at once and got mixed up. Fixed.  The other question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580264/in-php-what-is-the-difference-between-declaring-a-variable-as-global-inside-fun)

Comment: Added HTML template code example to question.  It's just basic HTML + a couple variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO. but here is the most popular way around it.

```
$rpl = array(
              '$variabe' => 'Hello or else!'
            );

$e_tpl = file_get_contents('/var/www/folder/email.php');
$body = str_replace(array_keys($rpl), array_values($rpl), $e_tpl);
$mail->Body = $body;
```

Then you can use `<p> $variable </p>` in email.php

Answer (score 1):

Well this question is mostly opinion based.. Nevertheless, in my opinion, you should use output buffering and just `include` your template file and then store the content of the buffer inside your `$html_email_body` variable.

Like this:

```
// 1. Turn on output buffering
ob_start();

// 2. Set your variables here
$variable = 'Hello or else!';

// 3. Include your template file, all output will be stored in a buffer
include '/var/www/folder/email.php';

// 4. Call ob_get_clean() to get the contents of the buffer
$html_email_body = ob_get_clean();

// 5. Send the email
$mail->Body    = $email_body;
PHPMailerFunc( $html_email_body );
```

Comment: Thank you!  Not my preferred method but I appreciate and learn from all alternatives.  `ob_start();` seems to be a real popular tool for many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the work for template engine - but don`t worry, is pretty easy to use.

Only thing you need is prepared project with [composer](https://getcomposer.org) and after that easily install one of the template engine (for this example I picked up [Latté](https://latte.nette.org/en/)).

Install of composer:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
```

after that installing Latté:

```
php composer.phar require latte/latte
```

And on the end, you can create something like this:

```
$latte = new \Latte\Engine;

$latte->setTempDirectory('/path/to/tempdir');

$parameters['variable'] = 'Hello or else';

$html = $latte->renderToString('email.latte', $parameters);
```

and put this content into file "email.latte" in same directory:

```
<p>{$variable}</p>
```

The good thing is - All variables are automatically escaped (to avoid XSS). So you are safer that if you are using just plain HTML.

Comment: Not the simplest method, but I appreciate the alternative and intro to Latte, thank you.