# In PHP, what is the difference between declaring a variable as global inside function, or passing the variable as an argument to the function?

Tags: php, function, global-variables, global

What is the difference between declaring a variable within a function as `global` or `public/private` VS passing it to a function as an argument?

**Other related confusion**

I've recently caused myself a big headache trying to pass aa array variable into a  function as `global` and editing it inside and hoping to return it altered, and it took me hours to figure out that I needed to pass it into the function as an argument by reference, like `functionCall(&$arrayVar);`

**Secondary question:** But I am still wondering, why doesn't it work to pass the variable in as `global` then edit it and spit it back out with `return` or simply by doing something like concatenating to the variable array?

Another example I recently ran into is by making a function for PHPMailer, where I am passing it several arguments, like email-to address and message body, but I also need to pass it authentication strings, like API key, etc.  Here, each time I call it:

1. I don't want to have to pass it the authentication credentials every time I call the PHMailer function (eg, to email error message at one of several stages)
2. But I do want to pass it unique arguments every time I call it

So I figured the best way is like this:

```
function phpMailer( $mail_to = "to@email.com", $mail_from = "a@b.com" ) {
    global $authCredentials;
}

// And of course, when I call phpMailer, I call it like
phpMailer("that.guy@there.com", "me@here.com");
```

**Tertiary question:** Is this appropriate usage of `global` or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Comment: The difference is that the latter is explicit. You know where the variable comes from and who is authorised to modify it.

Comment: a. they are basically identical

Comment: `global` is a misnomer. PHP doesn't really have global variables (apart from $_GET/POST/...). They're always scope-bound. If "passing it in" didn't work, then usually because you started out in a local scope and didn't rebind the variable name accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here, I will try to walk through them...

> What is the difference between declaring a variable within a function as global or public/private VS passing it to a function as an argument?

`global` is a type of [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Declaring a variable as `global` is generally considered bad practice and you should try to avoid it. By passing the variable to a function as an argument, the code is more reusable because you know what the function expects and it isn't relying on some unknown mystery global variable.

`public`, `private`, `protected` are types of [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) used in [object oriented programming](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). These basically determine how properties and methods within a class can be accessed by other classes.

> it took me hours to figure out that I needed to pass it into the function as an argument by reference

Something to understand about functions is that unless you [pass arguments by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference) you are working with a copy of the variable, not the original.

> why doesn't it work to pass the variable in as `global` then edit it and spit it back out with `return` or simply by doing something like concatenating to the variable array?

You wouldn't need to `return` a `global` variable, because you're working with the original value. Please refer again to the link above about scope.

> Another example I recently ran into is by making a function for PHPMailer, where I am passing it several arguments, like email-to address and message body, but I also need to pass it authentication strings, like API key, etc.

There are several ways to approach this in addition to using `global`. If you are planning to use this authentication key in more than one place, the easiest solution would probably be to define a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), for example:

```
define('AUTH', 'my_key');
function phpMailer( $mail_to = "to@email.com", $mail_from = "a@b.com" ) {
    echo AUTH;
}
```

But again, the function is now less reusable because it is dependent on that constant. A better solution would probably be to wrap it in an object:

```
class phpMailer()
{
    private $auth = 'my_key';

    public function send($mail_to, $mail_from)
    {
        $this->auth;
    }
}
$mail = new phpMailer();
$mail->send('to@email.com', 'a@b.com');
```

Hopefully this helps. The online PHP documentation found in the links above contain a wealth of information.

Comment: I am still studying this and the docs, days later.  Question:  by doing `global $someVar;` is `$someVar` now available through  `$GLOBALS['someVar']`?

Comment: Also, the `private ...  $this->auth;` method looks excellent but I store all my auth keys in a `config.ini.php` in sections (ie, `[gmail] api_key = "hello";  [api_2]...` then I get the keys via `$config = file_get_contents("config.ini.php");` and use it inside function as `global $config;`  Would it help to only instantiate the auth keys for their respective API function like `private $thisAPIConfigArray = $config["api_1"];`?